# can't install new packages after codeblocks

Tags: software-installation, code-blocks

I tried installing codeblocks from the tar.xg format but it didn't happen properly after that I can't purge or remove or delete codeblocks packages from my system and can't even install new software I have tried all the possible solution in the forums but still when I try to install anything this shows

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codeblocks : Depends: codeblocks-common (= 20.03-3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libcodeblocks0 (>= 20.03) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libtinyxml2.6.2v5 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: xterm
 libwxsmithlib0 : Depends: libcodeblocks0 (= 20.03) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: codeblocks-contrib (= 20.03) but it is not going to be installed
 wxsmith-dev : Depends: libcodeblocks0 (= 20.03) but it is not going to be installed
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken into consideration from this line: `You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.` for a solution? Try `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Also, have you tried to see if the package(s) is available as a .deb file or in the repository? `sudo apt install packageName`

Have you installed a higher version of the package(s) that the system can't handle? Try going to https://pkgs.org and find a specific version of a package you need.

For example, say package A is version 1.0 and package B and C (the dependencies) are also version 1.0, but you install a newer version of package A and it needs package B and C to be that same version, but you can't upgrade your system (if it's already up to date) than you probably should downgrade package A.

If you don't understand what I said above, let me know.